# Enable superuser when logged in with another user

Tags: sudo, users, root, privileges

Suppose that the machine has two users:

- Alice (admin)
- Bob (standard user)

While Bob is logged in, how can Alice modify a root file (Bob does not have this permission even with `sudo`)?

Alice tried:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/hosts
[sudo] password for Bob: 
Bob is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Comment: This is because Bob is not in the `/etc/sudoers` file. It just means that the administrator (Alice) does not trust Bob for administrative privileges.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `su`:

```
su - alice
sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

From `man su`:

```
   The su command is used to become another user during a login session.
   Invoked without a username, su defaults to becoming the superuser. The
   optional argument - may be used to provide an environment similar to
   what the user would expect had the user logged in directly.
```

For more information, see

```
man su
```

and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_%28Unix%29).

Comment: It works. Can you add please more information about this solution? Thanks!

Comment: See `man su`. `su` allows the user to log in to others' accounts. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_%28Unix%29

Comment: @enedil don't put additional information into a comment - edit you answer instead.